# Unwanted search bar with class input group from menu bar appearing on modal box

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a design the menu bar with `<nav>`tag.This menu bar contain the Login link and search field.
I have written a code in such a way that when I click on **Login** in a menu bar,modal box appear.But the problem is **the search field** which I had included in menu bar also appearing on the modal box.

code for search field

```
                  <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="search">
                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </form>
```

Please help me solve the issue.
Thanks to all.enter image description here
[image: This is the search bar with login]

[image: When I click on login link ,search bar from menu appear along with modal box]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its seems like the issue is with your z-index setting. Try changing search bar's z-index to something lower than that of modal's z-index.

```
.navbar-form {
   --
   --
   --
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -1;
}

.modalBox{
  --
  --
  --
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: What I want here ,when modal box appears then the search field should get disappear means modal box should display over search field

Comment: Then to hide the search field, you could use the negation of the same condition that is used for displaying the modalBox.. Also it will be good, if you could share the full html code of the nav bar..

Comment: Great.. Happy coding.. :-)